# create dir with todays date in batch file win server 2012

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008

Hi all ive had the following code running on a windows 2003 server and it runs fine.

```
echo on
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=- " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=- " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dd=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=- eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET mm=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=- " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%

mkdir C:\MySqlDbsBackup\%date%


mysqldump --user root --password=mypassword mydb > C:\MySqlDbsBackup\%date%\mydb.sql
```

were in the process of moving over to win server 2012 and for some reason the date is now "isEcho is on.12/12/2013"

and the only thing it creates dir wise is something called "isECHO"

thanks

Comment: check if the time settings are same on both machines.And the out of `date /t`

Answer (score 1):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.  You can tailor the date format for yourself.

Don't use `date` as a variable name because it is a system variable.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```